# Embedded structs get all tags and set values for all fields based on tag

Tags: go

I'm designing config component where I want to set ENV variable for each field on go struct.

e.g.

```golang
type SubStruct struct {
    Field int `env:"ENV_INT"`
}

type Config struct {
    Name string `env:"APP_NAME"`
    Sub1 struct {
        Sub11 struct {
            Value string `env:"ENV_VAR"`
        }
        Sub12 SubStruct
    } 
}
```

What I want to achieve is to:

1. Get values of all `env` keys recursively
2. Set value based on field type

So there are basically two questions:

- Is there any lib in go which exposes methods for setting values using reflection (e.g. like private methods in json package)?
- Is there any method/function in go which can parse your struct recursively and get all tags from struct?

---

edit: 
- updated structs
- renamed confusing field names (from embed to sub)

Comment: You can use `reflect` package for both of your points. And it might be worth pointing out, that what you have there in your Config type are not embedded structs/fields, they are plain fields of anonymous struct types. This matters because in Go there is such a concept as embedded fields but it's not what you have there.

Comment: Yes I know but don't want to implement all cases alone - you can look at encoding/json package - looks quite complicated :), in case of embedded fields they could be of course normal too.

Comment: just fyi embedded fields omit the field name, `Embed2 Embedded` is embedded only in name, ie it is not an embedded field. https://play.golang.com/p/GOl5PMAYqDQ

Comment: @mkopriva good point need to rename - bacause it's not Embedded in go struct meaning

Comment: Still I would recommend the `reflect` package. Looping through a struct with `reflect` is very simple, setting values may be a bit more demanding when considering different field types but still very simple. `encoding/json` might be complex but that's not because `reflect` is difficult to use, it's probably because of the multitude of different rules that need to be considered when dealing with json. A basic implementation won't take you more than 130 lines of code.

Comment: here's a modified, untested, copy of code i've written some time ago, it should get you halfway, if not all the way, to your solution ( https://play.golang.com/p/Vootuuu0X0X ). And, at the risk of being too nitpicky, your question, according to the general quidelines, is considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (see the 4th item). So you may want to consider either rephrasing it, or closing it altogether. *(added executable example)*